# show a required text field when a checkbox is checked in WooCommerce checkout

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I working on a solution in woocommerce registration with custom checkbox.

The plan is when somebody select the custom checkbox an additional textfield opens and have to be required.

The part that works:

```
// add the special customer role
add_action('admin_init', 'uiwc_new_role');
function uiwc_new_role() {  
    add_role(
        'kundenkarte',
        "Kundenkarte",
        array(
            'read'         => true,
            'delete_posts' => false
        )
    );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'custom_checkout_field_with_wholesale_option' );
function custom_checkout_field_with_wholesale_option( $checkout ) {

    if( current_user_can( 'wholesale_customer' ) ) return; // exit if it is "wholesale customer"

    echo '<div id="wholesale_checkbox_wrap">';
    woocommerce_form_field('wholesale_checkbox', array(
        'type' => 'checkbox',
        'class' => array('input-checkbox'),
        'label' => __('Do you have a Customer Card?'),
        'placeholder' => __('card'),
        'required' => false,
        'value'  => true
    ), '');
    echo '</div>';

}

// Conditionally change customer user role
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'wholesale_option_update_user_meta' );
function wholesale_option_update_user_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( isset($_POST['wholesale_checkbox']) ) {
        $user_id = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_customer_user', true ); // Get user ID
        if( $user_id > 0 ){
            $user = new WP_User($user_id);
            $user->remove_role('customer');
            $user->add_role('kundenkarte');
        }
    }
}
```

My PHP knowledge is very low.

Comment: Your addendum to the question was deleted, as it was posted in the answer space. You can reply instead to LoicTheAztec under their answer; if you want to show further code, you can use a GitHub Gist or a Pastie link.

Answer (score 3):

Updated (tested and works)

With the code below, when your checkbox is checked a custom required text field is visible (with validation and save as user meta data and order meta data):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'custom_checkout_field_with_wholesale_option' );
function custom_checkout_field_with_wholesale_option( $checkout ) {

    if( current_user_can( 'wholesale_customer' ) ) return; // exit if it is "wholesale customer"

    echo '<style> #wholesale_card_field.hidden { display:none; }</style>
    <div id="wholesale_checkbox_wrap">';

    woocommerce_form_field('wholesale_checkbox', array(
        'type' => 'checkbox',
        'class' => array('input-checkbox'),
        'label' => __('Do you have a Customer Card?'),
        'placeholder' => __('card'),
        'required' => false,
        'value'  => true
    ), '');

    woocommerce_form_field('wholesale_card', array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'class' => array('hidden'),
        'placeholder' => __('Customer card Id'),
        'required' => true,
    ), '');

    echo '</div>';

    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
        $('#wholesale_checkbox_field input').click(function(){
            if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('#wholesale_card_field').css('display', 'none').removeClass('hidden').show();
            } else if ( ! $(this).is(':checked') && $('#wholesale_card_field').css('display') !== 'none' ) {
                $('#wholesale_card_field').hide();
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php

}

// Validation
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wholesale_option_validation' );
function wholesale_option_validation() {
    if ( isset($_POST['wholesale_checkbox']) && isset($_POST['wholesale_card']) && empty($_POST['wholesale_card']) ) {
        wc_add_notice( __("Please fill in your customer card Id"), "error" );
    }
}

// Conditionally change customer user role and add customer card as order and user meta
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'wholesale_option_update_meta' );
function wholesale_option_update_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( isset($_POST['wholesale_checkbox']) ) {
        $user_id = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_customer_user', true ); // Get user ID
        if( $user_id > 0 ){
            $user = new WP_User($user_id);
            $user->remove_role('customer');
            $user->add_role('kundenkarte');
        }

        // Add customer card Id as order metadata
        if ( isset($_POST['wholesale_card']) ) {
            update_post_meta( $order_id, 'wholesale_card', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['wholesale_card'] ) );

            if( $user_id > 0 )
                update_user_meta( $user_id, 'wholesale_card', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['wholesale_card'] ) );
        }
    }
}

// Display customer card on admin order edit page under billing address
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'display_wholesale_option_admin_order', 10, 1 );
function display_wholesale_option_admin_order( $order ){
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Card Id').':</strong> ' . $order->get_meta( 'wholesale_card' ) . '</p>';
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: From a (now deleted) answer. "You can't use my answer code in an answer to your own question, as it's not fair" - this is not entirely true. It's certainly the case that someone should not take your code and then self-accept it (that would warrant a moderator flag, I think). However a person can take your code and build on it, as long as they give attribution; that is permitted within the licensing conditions. The fairness of who gets the acceptance mark (and how much labour was involved in the original and the modified copy) is then up to the question author.

Comment: @halfer Sorry but this is a new user that doesn't know StackOverFlow practices and have used an answer as a comment zone, thinking that I will be notified… I have not been talking about acceptance or votes at any moment... My "fairness" sentence is my personal opinion, that's all, and there is nothing wrong in it.

Comment: How do i vote for LoicTheAztec? is this select the small arrow?

Comment: Where must i write the textfield is not saving

Comment: hi, thanks i see it in order detals, but it was my question in to see it in user profile